# Better approach of saving images

Tags: javascript, image, upload, base64

I've created a form to register users and I have two ways of attaching a picture to the form:

1. *Taking a instant picture using flash:* In this approach, the picture is set on a graphicImage tag as base64 and then it would be saved into a string on the client bean.
2. *Uploading a picture on the hard drive:* In this approach, the picture is uploaded to the server and then the path is set on the graphicImage and the path saved on the bean.

So my question is:

In order to make the both approaches similar would it be better to encode the uploaded picture to base64 and save it on the bean, or upload the picture taken with flash and save its path on the bean?

Comment: I wanted to edit your question for readability, but I'm not sure about where the sentences are supposed to end - could you do it ? :P

Comment: How do you plan to retrieve and display the image?

Comment: Saving the path of the image into a bean and binding it to a graphicImage.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of data transferred in base64 is roughly 1/6th bigger than with binary data. However flash uploads might block/freeze the whole browser so I wouldn't recommend doing it.

The best way to do it (with a HTML5 browser) is to render the image to an HTML5 canvas and then use getImageData on the canvas to generate a (binary) upload.

There's a nice explanation on this here: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: I see. If I were to do like you said, is there anyway I could use the primeface library to do the upload or I would have to implement it another way?

Comment: I don't know the primeface library. The upload itself is pretty basic/standard stuff, so I would assume any client-side-library should be able to handle it.